# Columns specified more than once while JOINing temp tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'd like to join two temp tables into a third and final temp table. Below is the code I've written.

```
SELECT *
INTO ##ADAPS135
FROM ##ADA
JOIN ##PS135 PS ON PS.StudentID = ##ADA.StudentID
```

I receive an error message that reads:

> Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'StudentID' in
>   table '##ADAPS135' is specified more than once.

What can I do to fix this?

Please let me know if you need any more information! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

1) Don't use global temp tables

2) Give all your tables aliases

3) `select *` from at-most one of them

EG

```
SELECT ada.*, ps.SomeColumn, ps.OhterColumn, . . .
INTO #ADAPS135 
FROM #ADA ada
JOIN #PS135 PS 
  ON PS.StudentID = ada.StudentID
```